# Inline assembler execution time

Tags: winapi, assembly, inline-assembly

I would like to know how to count execution time of c++ inline assembler? 
My problem is that the difference of Tickcounts is 0.

Here is my cpp code:

```
const int N = 100000;
short x[4*N];

short a[4*N];
    for (int j=0;j<4*N;j++) {
        x[j] = rand() % 1000;
        a[j] = rand() % 5000;
    }
DWORD dwAStart = GetTickCount();

__asm {

    xor eax,eax

        mov ecx,N
    xor esi,esi
```

a1:

```
        emms
    movq        mm1,qword ptr x[esi]
    movq        mm2,mm1
    punpcklwd   mm1,mm6
    punpckhwd   mm2,mm6
    movq        mm0,qword ptr a[esi]
    movq        mm3,mm0
    punpcklwd   mm0,mm6
    punpckhwd   mm3,mm6
    pmullw      mm0,mm1

    paddsw      mm0,mm3

    add esi , 8
    loop a1
};
DWORD dwAInterval = GetTickCount() - dwAStart;
printf("Operation is completed through %d ms (Assembler)!\n", (int)dwAInterval);
```

Answer (score 2):

ticks, as counted by `GetTickCount()`, are too coarse to capture time differences from such short sequences of assembly code. You will have to use the x86 [Time Stamp Counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) to see the time; the instruction mnemonic is usually `RDTSC` in assembly. All caveats apply, such as: your process may get interrupted (this will invalidate the counts), the clock frequency may actually change, activity in other cores may affect the timing of your core, ....

Answer (score 2):

As GregS points out, GetTickCount is far too coarse to use for timing short sequences of code.  And the Time Stamp Counter found on x86 processors has limitations that make it very unreliable on multi-core processors.  The most reliable solution is the [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.  On *nix platforms, the POSIX function clock_gettime() serves a similar purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```html
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
int main()
{
  int X4,sum,avg;
  auto t1 = Clock::now();
  auto t2 = Clock::now();
  sum=avg=0;
  for( int i=0; i<TRIALS; i++ )
    {
      X4=17;
      t1 = Clock::now();
      asm  (
     "movl %0, %%eax;" // X->ax
     "movl $0x0A, %%ebx;" // 10->bx
     "mul %%ebx;" // 10*ax->ax
     : "=a" (X4)
     : "a" (X4)
     : "%ebx"
     );
      t2 = Clock::now();
      sum+=chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    }
  avg=sum/TRIALS;
  cout << "| Product:  " << X4<< "  "<< avg << " nanoseconds |" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Important: put the timing *outside* the repeat loop, otherwise you're mostly benchmarking the overhead.  [Why is inline assembler SOMETIMES faster and SOMETIMES slower in this code? Execution time varies quite a bit with each run](//stackoverflow.com/q/54931366).  (Unless you know exactly what you're doing with microbenchmarks using a low-overhead timesource like `rdtsc`, and are prepared to throw out outliers from interrupt-handlers delaying you.